# Realvnc changes keyboard layout when connecting to Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, virtualbox, keyboard-layout, screen-sharing, realvnc

I am running a guest macos High Sierra as virtual OS in Virtualbox.
To access the guest from host (also High Sierra) I can use :

1. Virtualbox gui
2. macos built in screen sharing with vnc://path/to/guest/OS
3. Realvnc

Screen sharing is enabled in guest, as it is necessary for 2 & 3 access.
1 & 2 have awaited AZERTY layout as configured in host and guest.

But 3 has QWERTY layout, that's the problem.

Nonetheless 3 has awaited AZERTY layout when connecting to raspberry configured with AZERTY layout...

2 & 3 are suitable to have copy/paste feature not available in Virtualbox for macos systems, but I would like to access the guest macos from other host OSes without the macos vnc built in function, so 2 is not an option.

Comment: The issue is a bug in screen sharing server (the remote end) rather than RealVNC's viewer. As you can see when connecting to your raspberry pi (which I assume is a RealVNC server) the key pressed on the viewer is correctly interpreted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the Mac VNC server, which is [well explained here](http://cafbit.com/entry/apple_remote_desktop_quirks).

The workaround is to switch either the client or the server (not both) to the English US layout. Still, some keys remain indeed problematic.

See also [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/644103/63361).

Answer (score -2):

uninstall realvnc and use anydesk or teamviewer. I tried tightvnc, realnvnc - always the same problem, the keyboard layout will change. On the MAC OS X you are able to add a 2nd keyboard "US internatinal PC", but in this time you have to change the keyboard (real/tight vnc = us international, mac os vnc your language). In the latest by entering a password you will be killed.

Its late, but I was looking for a solution too.